# Why is vscode vim.otherModesKeyBindingNonRecursive an unknown configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I had this setting for couple of weeks now but it stopped working today. This is a setting for vscode vim easymotion. I dont know what happened. I havent change anything. Does anyone know why?

OS macOS high Sierra.
Vscode Version 1.24.1 (1.24.1).
Vscodevim v0.14.0 .

```
 "vim.otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "s"
            ],
            "after": [
                "leader",
                "leader",
                "s"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive` has been replaced. [See pull request 2726 on the VSCodeVim project](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/2726). Instead see the current [Key Remapping section](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#key-remapping) in the project's README:

> Custom remappings are defined on a per-mode basis.
>
> "vim.insertModeKeyBindings"/"vim.normalModeKeyBindings"/"vim.visualModeKeyBindings"

Their example usage:

- Bind : to show the command palette:

```js
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": [":"],
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.showCommands",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```